# Magento 2 : Problem in reindexing site

Tags: magento2, reindex, websites

I have created two users with certains access in BO and I found that when adding category or product even an article ( via an extension that I have already installed) I can't find the new rows added without launching certain command : indexer: reindex, flush cache so  it's a problèm for the client because he will fed up with reindexing his site every time his don't  find the updated changes so how to prevent this issue and do I have to install certain extension or what please any clear explanation and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

set the indexer setting to "reindex on save" un "System -> Index Management"

but keep in mind that this will slow down your site

Comment: Is there any other way? I am having the same problem but in my case every time I need to reindex if a product is out of stock.

Comment: @iqbalmalik set the stock indexer to "update on save"

Comment: You can do it with the help of symlinks. Create symlinks for your project and then you wont have to run commands.

Comment: @sugar how are symlinks supposed to help here?

Comment: thanks for your replay but i want to find   a solution that don't slow my site and in same time resolve the issue of reindexing the site

Comment: @DevelopperMagento You can't have the best of both worlds

Comment: so  no deal to resolve this issue  without infleuncing the performance of the site

Comment: @DevelopperMagento just test it out. it's not like the performance goes to unusable.

Comment: ok Philipp i will  test this and really thanks for your replay